# How to create a Horizontal Tabbed Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a horizontal tabbed menu-bar for eg. Package Introduction | Package Description | Package Cost

So when I click on a tab, that particular  will slide-in from the side; and by default "Package Introduction" will be visible at first.

So can you please suggest me the code to achieve this. Giving preference to jQuery usage.
I have done this code, which is lame and a no-brainer. I'm looking for a better way to achieve this. Preferably jQuery, but not a jQuery plugin/project. Only 3-4 lines of jQuery code to help me with selection and animation.

```
    <html><head>
</head>
<style>
.tabs_bar {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Open Sans Light", "Myriad Pro Light", "Roboto Lt";
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
.tabs_list {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs_list>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tabs_list>li a {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #CCC;
}
.tabs_list>li a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
.active {}
.tabs_list>li a.active {
    color: #F00;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.tab_body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
}
.box {
    background: #FFF;
    display: none;
}
.box:target {
    display: block;
}
.tab_body_list {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tab_body_list>li {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<body>


<!-- tab bar -->
    <div class="tabs_bar">
    <ul class="tabs_list">
        <li><a href="#hotels" class="active">hotels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#meals">meals</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--end tab bar --></div>

    <!-- tab body -->
    <div class="tab_body">
    <ul class="tab_body_list">
        <li><div id="hotels" class="box">dflkjkjdjkdhmkjnhhgunhusjriondiuhuehgds<br>gheruhiuhriuewhiuheiugiueji</div></li>
        <li><div id="meals" class="box">dklsjhjkdhbkdhkhkdhs sighshgsiuhgsuhgj sushgus<br>skuhushushu</div></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end tab body --></div>

    kdsjnhfvmnhj hndkuhdvhjdnhcjhdbkldfbfklnhklnhklbnklesbeklbwklbnkhwlnhklwrhibgwhlkgwkllkbngklrwnhbkwhklwnhkl

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may find this of use for your CSS - http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/IJKqg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understood what you were asking for, I havent played around to much with your CSS, but you can do that to get the desired effect, but I think this is what you were looking for.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/4/)

```
$('#hotel').click(function(){
    $('#hotels').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $('#hotels').fadeIn();
    $('#meals').fadeOut();
});

$('#Meal').click(function(){
    $('#meals').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $('#meals').fadeIn();
    $('#hotels').fadeOut();
});
```

I hope you find what you are looking for.

**EDIT:**
Turns out I had some more time, so I fixed the fiddle up a little, and removed a line of Jquery.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. But, actually I wanted the whole body to slide-in from the side, on click of the tab; and the old body to slide-out.
Can't I do the whole without the use of <ul>'s & <li>'s; with the use of only <div>'s ? I'm actually trying to improve what I've done; with some other better way.

Comment: Have a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/5/ ... Hopefully I am understanding you correctly, You want your "Hotels" text to slide out, and the body should slide out as well?? I have updated the fiddle to do that with the hotel link. Cheers.

Comment: no no no... I don't want he hotels text to slide out. The tabs should be intact. Only the body part of the corresponding tab should slide-out and slide-in

Comment: ok. This should do. I can now tinker with the properties to get what i wanted. But, most importantly, I should have to grab a good jQuery book and learn. Thanks for the help, Mike

Comment: Here is another updated fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/6/  (Hopefully this is what you want - haha) like you mentioned earlier, you can remove your list items and just create Divs.

Just play around with what you want to hide vs display and then slide it in... Also, as an FYI the "1000" you see in the jQuery is the time it takes to complete the animation, play with that as well to achieve your desired result. GOOD LUCK MAN!!

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! CHEERS !!
But there is still a minor problem. i.e. Whenever a particular tab is open; and I click on the same tab again; then there should be no animation. i.e(if meals tab is open, and I click on Meals tab again; there should be no animation);

Comment: Hi Souravmoy - after being in quite a pickle myself with your last request, see the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/16/

Comment: HOTELTEXTHOTELTEXTHOTELTEXHOTELTEXTHOTELTEXT

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab_body_list li:first-child .box').css('display','block') ;
    $('.tabs_list li').click(function(){
     var ind =  $(this).index();
        $('.tab_body_list li .box').css('display','none') ;
    $('.tab_body_list').children('li').eq(ind).children('.box').css('display','block') ;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/679z9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery tabs for this. Refer the link below.  source code and demo is there

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: I've seen that; but I'm not into using plugins/ui's.
What I'm looking for can be achieved with a few lines of jQuery; but unfortunately I don't know jQuery that well.